# get the element posistion using jquery/javascript in Android orientation change

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I want to get an element position from left and i m using below code.

```
function fun () {
......
var pos= $('.highlight_link')[0].offsetLeft
alert(pos);
......
}

window.onorientationchange = function() {
             ........
             fun();
             ......
}
```

here highlight_link is the class applied to elements. All the elements are vertically aligned. Hence taking first is ok here.

Now in android version 2.3.6 ; in Portrait mode if the value of "pos" is 230 and switch the mode to Landscape I am getting proper position ( say 540) as expected relative to orientation.

But if i run the same code in Android 4.0.4 then I get my old orientation offset. i.e. if in Portrait mode value of pos is "230" then switching orientation to Landscape it will agin give the pos value as "230".

But if i start my web-app in landscape mode only, then i gets proper value of pos ( say 540) in both android versions.

Please let me know how can I get proper position value. Position of the element has been set in highlight_link class. If it is like that CSS is being applied after jquery then how can i avoid this situation in 4.0.4.